# Which .xml dump to use for wikidata?

Tags: wiki, wikidata

I'm looking at the Wikidata .xml dumps and am getting a little lost.
I'm looking for (ideally) a complete dump in the format of the add/delete daily .xml dumps found at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/incr/wikidatawiki/ as it is the edit history that I'm interested in.

Thanks!